# Is it an ANTLR4 EOF Bug or My Error

Tags: antlr4

This is my trimmed down ANTLR4 grammar (note I'm using a constant false to replace my method that returns false ):

```
grammar AnnotProcessor;
    cppCompilationUnit:  content+ EOF;

    content: anything  
           | {false}? .; 

    anything: ANY_CHAR;

    ANY_CHAR: [_a-zA-Z0-9];
```

My test file contains only 1 word **"hello"** and the test results are like these:

```
D:\work\antlr4\work>java org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig AnnotProcessor cppCompilationUnit -tree in.cpp
line 1:5 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'
(cppCompilationUnit (content (anything h)) (content (anything e)) (content (anything l)) (content (anything l)) (content (anything o)))

D:\work\antlr4\work>java org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig AnnotProcessor cppCompilationUnit -tokens in.cpp
[@0,0:0='h',<1>,1:0]
[@1,1:1='e',<1>,1:1]
[@2,2:2='l',<1>,1:2]
[@3,3:3='l',<1>,1:3]
[@4,4:4='o',<1>,1:4]
[@5,5:4='<EOF>',<-1>,1:5]
line 1:5 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'
```

Why it keeps saying "line 1:5 no viable alternative at input '< EOF >'" when I add a semantic predicate (although a dummy here) as an alternative?  If I remove the alternative with the false semantic predicate, the error disappears as expected.

PS: I'm using antlr-4.0-complete.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug. In ANTLR 4, the introduction of an alternative starting with `{false}?` [almost] anywhere in the grammar should not affect the parse result for any [valid] input.

Can you report the issue here:
https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues

**Edit: This is issue #218, now fixed**
https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/218

PS: Your use of the non-greedy operator `+?` is either unnecessary or incorrect in the `cppCompilationUnit` rule. If you meant to require at least one `content` element, you can simply use `+`. However, what I think you meant to write is zero-or-more `content` elements: `(content+)?`, which can be simplified to just `content*`.

Comment: My original post used a non-greedy + for "content" which, upon further testing, causes no error. The error appears only if a greedy one is used. Pls see my edited grammar.  Is it normal?